# In MFC how to access CView from CWinAppEx

Tags: c++, mfc

I do not have great expertise in MFC. I have a MFC application with the basic setup: single document application. Now In the project I have the most standard setup: one ...View class one ...Doc class and one ...WinAppEx class. These three represents the model-view-controller design principle respectively. I do not find a way to access View class from the WinAppEx class.

My actual use case is I have some command line arguments passed to the app. I want to display these arguments on my primary view. To access those arguments I have in my ...WinAppEx::InitInstance() method

```
CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);
```

Now I need to pass arguments to the view. I have tried ::GetMainWnd() and traverse its siblings and its children. I also tried ::GetNextDocTemplate() and then ::GetNextDoc() and then ::GetNextView(). I still did not find my ...View instance. Can you please shed some light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you **HAVE** to access the view from the application?  Why not access the application from the view? From the view class you can call `AfxGetApp()` and get the command line arguments.  Also, for a very simple app, usually there is a global variable defined by the wizard called "`theApp`".

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to access the CView before it has been created. At the end of the InitInstance function you can cast the m_pMainWnd to a CMainFrame* and use that pointer to call CMainFrame's GetActiveView() function.